# FAILED Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry

I have two Jenkins jobs calling a third job in parallel.

The third job contains :

1. login to cloud foundry which is a diff job.
2. doing something.
3. Logout from cloud foundry which is a diff job as well.

When running the two jobs in parallel and one of them finish first, the second one fails with the below error:

```
FAILED
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
```

Could someone help me to solve this?

Many things :)

Comment: So the third job has logic to login to cloudfoundry, working on it and log out?

Comment: yes, and the other two are calling it, each one separately.

Comment: I believe, |you need to create a logic to have this functionality in a block, for eg. inside a  `withCredentials` condition. Can you share your login , logout logic? what type of cloud server you using? gaia etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cf CLI caches your refresh token and other information locally in `$CF_HOME/.cf/config.json`. When you call the third job in parallel, one process could be updating (or deleting from) that file while the other process tries to read from it, causing unexpected results as you're seeing.

You could set environment variable `CF_HOME` to something unique, e.g. to a random unique folder you create in /tmp, or to a folder with the invoking job's number if available, to ensure the processes do not collide:

`CF_HOME=$(mktemp -d /tmp/cfhome.XXXXXXXXX)
cf auth ...
cf ...
cf logout
rm -rf $CF_HOME`